# How can an Apache user write files when having permissions to do it?

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I'm with a web application that let anonymous users to upload images, transform them and get them later. I have a directory with `www-data` group owner and `1770` permissions, where the images are uploaded. In Apache configuration, `AllowOverride` set to `none` and `Options` to `-Indexes`.
The input validation is controlled, so would be difficult to exploit. 
The question is:

**How could anyone write files in that directory (if input validation is controlled), where Apache user has permissions to do it?**

**And what changes when the permissions are set to `777`?**

Comment: Somebody just using your web application is not a “user” from the perspective of your server.

Comment: @CBroe - What does it change?

Comment: The change is: it is NOT of interest in the files system perspective, so no need to play around with linux file system permissions, because it's ALLWAYS the apache user and group accessing the files.